# Save data to a json file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dataframe, python-requests

I would like to save a JSON file from the variable 'data' through an API.

I've created a function writetoJsonfile to do it but it does not work.

Can you guys help me out? Thank you.

import requests,json,io
import xmltodict
import logging as log
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from datetime import datetime

def writeToJSONFile(path, filename, cs ):

```
path = 'C:/Users/Skelaton/Desktop'
filename = 'compromised_systems'
ext = 'json'

filePathNameWExt = path + filename + ext 

with open(filePathNameWExt, 'w') as fp :
            json.dump(cs, fp)

def getdata(person_id):

    log.info("Downloading all data from people {}".format(person_id))

    payload = {'format' : 'csv'}
    r = requests.get
    ("https://example.com/people/{}/reports/person".format(person_id),
        auth=(api_key,''), proxies=proxy,params=payload)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        data = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(r.content),error_bad_lines=False)
        data = data.to_json(orient="records")
        data = json.loads(data)    
        return data    
    else:
        log.error("Unable to download all data due to status code : 
        {}".format(r.status_code))
    return False
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? also write the `imports` that you're using in this code.

Comment: Expressions like "*does not work*" aren't well received. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Looking at your code, I see that `filePathNameWExt = path + filename + ext` is indented **by only 2 spaces**, not by 4 as the rest of them. Add 2 more spaces in front of it, and you should be fine (unless you introduced *typo*s when pasting the code).

Comment: ``ext`` is not defined anywhere. But as others said, please create a [mcve] and make sure the code in your question is indented and formatted correctly.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the feedback :) I've added the imports. I do not have any error when I execute the program but there's not any file created in my desktop..

Comment: Try to print filePathNameWExt. I think it should be C:/Users/Skelaton/Desktopcompromised_systemsjson, instead of C:/Users/Skelaton/Desktop/compromised_systems.json

Answer (score 1):

Your file path doesn't seem right.
This works:

```
path = 'C:/Users/Skelaton/Desktop/'
filename = 'compromised_systems'
ext = '.json'

filePathNameWExt = path + filename + ext 

def write_to_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w+') as fp:
        fp.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: We appreciate your prompt response and eager to get the answer accepted. But please do explain why your code works, the approach and what the questioner did wrong. By looking at your code I got a question why do you think `w+` is fine but not `w`?

Comment: Since the question contains no stack trace, there are 2 differences I can observe. One is the indentation, the other I am using json.dumps() rather than json.dump() function of json module.

Comment: Add this explanation to the question instead of the comments!